# How to export List settings

Tags: export

I have several lists in my SharePoint 2010 and I'm seeking how to export the list settings - mainly the columns name and type (e.g.  Name which is single line of text).

How can I do this?

(this isn't the same as exporting the list that has data in it so I can save my data in a spreadsheet).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

you will need to save the list as a template. when doing this you will have the option to save the content along with it. Then when you create a new list use that template.

Comment: Actually, I just tried the template method and it just makes me an template.  No option to export (or save) the list settings (columns and types) to a text file or spreadsheet.

Comment: list settings -> save list as template -> then you should have a check box at the bottom that says "Include Content"

Answer (score 2):

You can go to the list settings page and click Save list as template - it will create a template that allows to clone list structure with or without its data.

Comment: Will this actually let me export (or save) the list settings so say, a text file, or spreadsheet?

Comment: No, there's no such OOTB functionality. It's relatively easy to implement it with Visual Studio but I don't understand what's the goal?

Answer (score 0):

Is this 2010?
There is a button available in the ribbon when viewing the list - "Export to Excel".  That should do what you want.

Comment: Sorry folks.  Every solution here was to export the content of a list (data someone input).  Not what I was looking for.  I just copied and pasted (to notepad) my list settings.  Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same question come up at work. The point was if SharePoint was corrupted and you had to rebuild lists and libraries, you'll have the settings saved (column types/names; sorting settings; view ranges) without having to guess at what those were when they were made. Right now our option is to go into each library/list setting and write down our selections in advanced settings.

Comment: Hi Jess, was this intended as a comment on the original question? If you wanted to add a comment but lack the required privileges, you can flag this post for a mod to review. Just leave a notice in the flag reason field.

Answer (score 0):

When trying to keep a saved version of a particular view on a list I came across the use of Chrome. If you are in a chrome Browser (whilst looking at your settings/views) you can do ctrl-P - then save as pdf. this will create a documented record file of the settings/view settings for you.
cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this. Some of our users want to build the data in Excel and cut and paste it into SharePoint. They need the cell criteria / choices / validation from SharePoint. One can maintain an Excel clone of the original list but that takes time of the list settings are evolving. Hence the need to export the template into an Excel form with the validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

10 years later ....  Add the tables to an Access Database as live linked tables and use the Database Documenter function.  It's cumbersome and you have to be careful not to ask for too much, but it will give you what you're looking for.